# State resets when receiving socket message

Tags: reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io, next.js

I'm trying to create a chat application with Next, Express and Socket.io.
The problem I'm facing is the following:
I have 2 browsers, I send a message from the first one and I see it in the second browser, but if I send another message, the state that manages the messages (array of strings) resets everytime, [here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxMkd.gif).

Backend:

```
import express from 'express'
import http from 'http'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import cors from 'cors'

const PORT = 3001
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  }
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User connected: ${socket.id}`)

  socket.on("join_chat", (data) => {
    socket.join(data)
  })

  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    console.log(`Mensaje recibido: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
    socket.to(data.chat).emit("receive_message", data)
  })
})

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Frontend

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001")

export default function Home() {
  const [chat, setChat] = useState("")
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

  const joinChat = () => {
    if(chat)
      socket.emit("join_chat", chat)
  }

  const addMessage = (newMessage) => {
    setMessages(() => [...messages, newMessage])
  }

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("send_message", {
      message,
      chat,
    })
    addMessage(message)
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      addMessage(data.message)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text"
        value={chat}
        placeholder="Chat room number"
        onChange={(e) => setChat(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => joinChat()}
      >Click</button>

      <input type="text"
        value={message}
        placeholder="Message"
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => sendMessage()}
      >Click</button>

      <h1>Received messages</h1>
      {messages.length > 0 && messages.map((message, index) => 
        <li key={index}>{message}</li>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm new to using websockets and how to implement it in React I was trying everything I could think of just to solve it, so finally I ended up taking out the `socket.on("receive_message"...` of the `useEffect` and now it works, don't know if it is the right solution but it works.

Now frontend looks like:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001")

const Home = () => {
  const [chat, setChat] = useState("")
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

  const joinChat = () => {
    if(chat)
      socket.emit("join_chat", chat)
  }

  const addMessage = (newMessage) => {
    setMessages(() => [...messages, newMessage])
  }

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("send_message", {
      message,
      chat,
    })
    addMessage(message)
  }
  
  // useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      addMessage(data.message)
    })
  // }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text"
        value={chat}
        placeholder="Chat room number"
        onChange={(e) => setChat(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => joinChat()}
      >Click</button>

      <input type="text"
        value={message}
        placeholder="Message"
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => sendMessage()}
      >Click</button>

      <h1>Received messages</h1>
      {messages.length > 0 && messages.map((message, index) => 
        <li key={index}>{message}</li>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: If you comment out receive message as you've shown in the updated code, you no longer have an event handler that responds to the emit from your back end. I'm currently am having the same problem. It seems like your state will no longer reset but also that You no longer can receive a message on the front end.

Comment: @JohnyClash The thing that I commented out is just the useEffect, the `socket.on("receive_message", ())` that handles the emit from the backend is still there and I think this was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the state update by using the previous state to retain the previous state value and avoid the state reset. Create a function that updates your state variable on receiving a message. Call this function inside useEffect, keeping the value of your socket as a dependency so that state updates everytime the socket emits an event

```
  function receiveMessage() {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on(events.RECEIVE_MESSAGE, (data) => {
        setMessageList((prev) => [...prev, data]);
      });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    receiveMessage();
  }, [socket]);
```